# sparse matrix multiplication using MKL libraries

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I was looking to find a way to perform a symmetric sparse matrix - matrix multiplication:
X = A B
where the sparse matrix A was previously stored in CSR3 format (upper triangular), while the matrix B is a dense non-symmetric matrix. Is there a routine inside the MKL libraries to do it? or do they all need the full sparse matrix in CSR format (to get the handle from) instead of the triangular one (I built the triangular matrix because I need to use it in MKL Pardiso)? I know about the *mkl_sparse_d_mv(...)* routine, but I couldn't find a way to get the sparse matrix handle from a symmetric sparse matrix previously stored like an upper triangular matrix in CSR format.
thank you in advance,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the mkl_sparse_?_mm, where [?] == s,d,c and z data types.
This routine performs a matrix-matrix operation:

Y := alpha*op(A)*X + beta*Y
where alpha and beta are scalars, A is a sparse matrix, op is a matrix modifier for matrix A, and X and Y are dense matrices.

Comment: Thank you Gennady, but how to get the handle (op(A)) to the matrix struct if I only have the triangular CSR matrix A (i.e. CSR3 or CSR vectors) ? is it needed to build the full CSR matrix to get the handle from?

Comment: no, I don't think you need to build the full CSR.  Checking with documentation, I see that the descriptor supports SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_SYMMETRIC mode.  Therefore you could declare something like 
descrA.type = SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_SYMMETRIC and put this descriptor to the mkl_sparse_?_mm(....) routine.

Comment: Thanks Gennady, yes, it seemed to work fine, but later I noticed results I obtain by mkl_sparse_d_mm() are different from what I evaluated by using, for example, matlab. I've just written a message on the Intel MKL forum too, asking for some help https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/mkl-sparse-d-mm-problem/td-p/1188433

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can easily feed a CSR3-stored matrix into `sparse_d_create_csr` by passing appropriately offset pointers to your row index for pointerB and pointerE.

You can then tell `mkl_sparse_d_mm` the sparse matrix is triangular and you'd like it to be filled (I have never done this and can't promise that it works).

Comment: I was wrong, it seems it doesn't work, maybe it needs the full matrix in CSR format instead of the triangular one. I noticed it works fine only if the sparse matrix (that I entered as a triangular matrix in CSR format) is diagonal. Here the link https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/mkl-sparse-d-mm-problem/td-p/1188433 where I asked for some help in the Intel MKL forum (unanswered at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I can now say the routine needs the full matrix in CSR format, the matrix struct description it will only tells the routine to take one triangle(upper/lower) from the input full CSR matrix, but still it needs it all.

Comment: well, I was wrong again, it just needed to use the flag SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_SYMMETRIC instead of SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_TRIANGULAR and it's possible to insert the upper/lower triangular part of the sparse matrix. It's not mandatory to build the full CSR matrix if the sparse matrix is symmetric. It finally works 100%.